# Control video on youtube page

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video

what I want: I want to control pause/play on in a youtube page, not api, a youtube page, like: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IcrbM1l_BoI
I tried to search in the code, but failed.

Comment: Anything you have tried?

Comment: no, not anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `pause()` and `play()` functions, youtube video uses the `video-stream` class on the player so you can do it like this:

```
var video = document.querySelector(".video-stream");
video.pause();
video.play();
```